# Where is the "physicial volume for RAID" partition type in the Ubuntu 18.04 installer ? Trying to use RAID1

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, system-installation, raid

*I know this question has been asked multiple times already, and that there's a bunch of tutorials out there, but they all seem to be outdated, or have conflicting information.*

I'm looking to install Ubuntu 18.04 Server on two 80GB drives in RAID 1, in order to allow for one drive to fail. In order to do that, I read that you first have to create two partitions on each drive (a SWAP partition and a "physicial volume for RAID"). Unfortunately, there is no option available that even remotely resembles "physicial volume for RAID". I'm presented with "EXT4", "XFS", "BTRFS", "SWAP", "leave unformatted".

I've looked for some video tutorials in order to find out which option to select, as I've learned that they seem to be more accurate, but they all use a third disk (which IMO defeats the point of RAID 1).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you see this: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html.en

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yes, did you read the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the non-live 'alternative' image from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/

Images with 'live' in the name have fewer advanced options which is why the tutorials seem to not apply. They're for the non-live version. It's not obvious from landing at the download page from search engine, that's for sure.

Comment: Seems plausible but unfortunately no longer able to test as I no longer have access to the server. Thanks for your response though!